# how to call a url from a java action in struts?

Tags: java, struts

i am trying to send sms through a url as follows

```
public  void sendsms() throws IOException 
    {
  URL sms = new URL("http://india.timessms.com/http-       api/receiverall.asp?username=way2sijo&password=*******i&sender=Demo&cdmasender=9930065297&to=919930065297&message=Hello");
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
     new InputStreamReader(sms.openStream()));

  String inputLine;

  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
      System.out.println(inputLine);

  in.close();
  }
```

but while running this one showing following exceptions

```
in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
```

how can i solve this problam.......thanks in advance.......

Answer (score 1):

It is better you look at apache http client library and make a get request using it.